# Inner product over complex and real field

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying some inner product and I am confused about inner space over different fields.
If I have a complex vector space $V$ it is a a vector space over the reals and complex field.
For example, $\mathbb{C^2}$ has basis{$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$} over $\mathbb{C}$ which is an orthonormal basis?
However over $\mathbb{R}$ a basis is{$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix} i\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ i\end{pmatrix}$.
Is this an orthonormal basis ? How are we defining the inner product in second case?

If I have subspace $S := \{(1,0),(0,i)\} $, over the field of real numbers how to find $S^\perp$.

Comment: Well, that is the question: you have to specify both the vector space **and** the inner product space. Note that as a *real* vector space, $\mathbb{C}^2$ is four-dimensional. But you need to specify an inner product before you can ask whether a set is orthonormal, or what an orthogonal complement is.

Comment: Now, there *is* a common way of taking a complex inner-product space, and defining a real inner product space on the same collection of vectors. If $V$ is a complex inner product space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\,\cdot\rangle$, then you can view $V$ as a **real** vector space by restriction of scalars, and then define the inner product $[\cdot,\,\cdot]$ on $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ by $[x,y]=\mathcal{R}e(\langle x,y\rangle)$, the real part of $\langle x,y\rangle$. Perhaps that is what you are doing in the second example?

Comment: For the complex vector spaces, you want the [Hermitian product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html).